# full_join data with 0 rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to write a function that supports joining data with 0 rows, but I get this error:

```
a<-tibble("key", "value", .rows=0)
b<-tibble(key = c("test1","test2"), value=c("result1","result2"))
full_join(a, b, by="key") # Bombs

# Error: `by` can't contain join column `key` which is missing from LHS

merge(a, b, by="key") # Also bombs 

# Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Desired output is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  key   value.x value.y
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 test1 NA      result1
2 test2 NA      result2
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or any ideas for a workaround without a bunch of conditional logic using `nrows()==0`?

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Comment: The output in the accepted answer below is great. I'll add it to the question as well for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define an empty `tibble` using `character()`, `integer()` etc ...

```
library(tibble)
a<-tibble(key=character(), value=character())
b<-tibble(key=c("test1","test2"), value=c("result1","result2"))

full_join(a, b, by='key')
```

We got this Error

> Error: `by` can't contain join column `key` which is missing from LHS

Because `a<-tibble("key", "value", .rows=0)` returns `a` with a column named `"key"` not `key` hence `full_join` will fail.

Comment: Interesting observation. The column names in `a` as the asker generates it at `"keys"` and `"value"` with the quotes included. Weird

Comment: @divibisan I think this is the default behavior, same as in `data.frame("key", "value")`. When the user didn't provide column names  `tibble` and `data.frame` used the values as column names.

Comment: Yes - what strange behaviour with the quoted column names! Thanks for the quick and clear answer @A.Suliman.